# Is Pentecost observed in Lisbon?

Tags: public-holidays, religion, lisbon

Is there anything special going on in Lisbon on the day of Pentecost? My tourist guide for Portugal mentions that this day is widely celebrated in the Azores, and that in Braga penitents can be seen climbing the staircase at Bom Jesus on their knees, but it doesn't say anything about Lisbon.

Is the day observed in Lisbon as well, or any place close to it?

As a side question, is the following Monday a public holiday in Portugal? Pentecost falls on Sunday May 24th this year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt there is anything specific for Pentecost in Lisbon.

Searching for events in Lisbon around that date on multiple websites was not successful. The [tourism website for Lisbon](http://www.visitlisboa.com/Conteudos/Eventos/Pesquisa-Eventos.aspx?dia=24&mes=5&ano=2015) did not return any match for that day, neither [Lonely Planet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/portugal/lisbon/events). Typing "Pentecostes Lisboa" in a search engine ending up pointing to [a vigil of Pentecost](http://www2.juventude.patriarcado-lisboa.pt/events/event/vigilia-de-pentecostes/) so if you are religious you should be  able to find a church with a specific mass.

Regarding Pentecost Monday, unlike said on some [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentecost#Public_holiday), it does not seem to be a public holiday in Portugal. Multiple [websites](http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/portugal/), including [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_Portugal), do not list it as a public holiday.

However, it seems a few towns have a public holiday on the Monday or Tuesday after Pentecost, but mostly in the North of the country, as listed on the [portuguese Wikipedia page for public holidays](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feriados_em_Portugal#Datas_m.C3.B3veis).